# Time complexity of :: and @ (OCaml)

Tags: list, queue, append, ocaml, time-complexity

I was reading [this](https://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/OCaml_Coding_Considerations) and was wondering if `::` is always more efficient than @ or if only in that particular implementation of `rev`

```
let rec rev = function
  | [] -> []
  | h::t -> rev t @ [h]

let rev l =
  let aux accu = function
    | [] -> accu
    | h::t -> aux (h :: accu) t
```

For example, if I wanted to append an element on a queue, would there be a difference in these two methods:

```
let append x q = q @ [x]
```

and

```
type 'a queue = {front:'a list; back:'a list}
  let norm = function
    | {front=[]; back} -> {front=List.rev back; back=[]}
    | q -> q

  let append x q = norm {q with back=x::q.back}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@` is `O(n)` in the size of its left operand. `::` is `O(1)` and `List.rev` (as defined in the standard library) is `O(n)`.

So if you apply `@` `n` times, you get an `O(n^2)` algorithm. But if you apply `::` n times, that's only `O(n)` and if you then reverse the result once at the end, it's still `O(n)`. This is true in general and for that reason any algorithm that appends to the end of a list multiple times, should instead prepend to the beginning of the list multiple times and then reverse the result.

However your example is different. Here you're replacing one single use of `@` with one possible use of `rev`. Since both are `O(n)`, you end up with the same complexity in the case where you use `rev`.

However the case where you use `rev` won't happen a lot, so the complexity of enqueuing `n` should end up amortized O(n) (and if you don't dequeue anything in between, it's just plain O(n)). Whereas your version using `@` would lead to `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 1):

> I was reading this and was wondering if :: is always more efficient than @

Basically yes, but the question is blurry enough to find very special cases where both are as efficient.

The *efficiency* or the *complexity* of an operation is typically expressed using an asymptotic equivalent of the computing cost of this operation in terms of the size of its input.  That said we can compare precisely the complexity of `::` and `@` by stating:

1. The complexity of computing `x :: lst` is *O(1)*, that is, it is bounded by a constant cost independant of the inputs.
2. The complexity of computing `a @ b` is *O(List.length a)*.

(The notation used is called *big-O notation* or *Landau notation* and should be described in most computer science textbooks.)

> For example, if I wanted to append an element on a queue, would there be a difference in these two methods:

These two methods have equivalent complexity, running in *O(length q)*.  The complexity of the second operation is carried by the `List.rev` operation.