# Reversing a list in SML

Tags: list, sml

```
fun reverse ( [] ) = ( [] )
  | reverse (x::xs) = reverse (xs) :: [x]
```

why my this function of reversing a list is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function has type `'a list -> 'a list`. `::` has type `'a -> 'a list -> 'a list`. Thus you can't pass the result of calling `reverse` as the first argument to `::`.

You could use `@` [as suggested by JRose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73596732/15261315) because that has type `'a list -> 'a list -> 'a list` and will concatenate the two lists but that is inefficient compared to `::`. `@` is O(n). Using it makes `reverse` have O(n^2) runtime efficiency.

Instead, let's use a tail-recursive helper function to build up an accumulator list in reverse order *using* `::`, then return that. Because `::` is O(1), this has O(n) runtime efficiency which is *much* better than O(n^2).

```
fun reverse lst = 
  let
    fun aux [] acc = acc
      | aux (x::xs) acc = aux xs (x :: acc)
  in
    aux lst []
  end
```

Consider reversing `[1, 2, 3]`:

```
reverse [1, 2, 3]
aux [1, 2, 3] []
aux [2, 3] [1]
aux [3] [2, 1]
aux [] [3, 2, 1]
[3, 2, 1]
```

[Further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40008949/time-complexity-of-and-ocaml) on the efficiency of `@` and `::`. The link talks about OCaml, but the core principles are the same in SML.